# How can i store the result of a comparison into a variable

Tags: t-sql

I want to print a simple statement 
print (1=1), i expect the result to be TRUE or 1 but sql server tell me:
Incorrect syntax near '='.
why is that?

Same will happen for a statement like that

```
declare @test bit
set @test = (1=1)
```

in summary how can i "see" what is returned from a comparison without using an IF statement

Update: The reason i'm asking is because i'm trying to debug why the following statement

```
declare @AgingAmount smallint
set @AgingAmount = 500
select Amount, datediff(day,Batch.SubmitDate,getdate()) as Aging from myreporrt
where datediff(day,Batch.SubmitDate,getdate()) > @AgingAmount
```

will return all rows even with aging of 300
    so i wanted to test if datediff(day,datesubmited,getdate()) > 500 returns true or false but could not find a way how to display the result of this comparison.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the exact query you are trying to execute?

Comment: I should actually change the title for this question to "How can i display the result of a comparison without using an if statement"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although SQL Server has the concept of a`boolean` type, and it understands expressions that resolve to a `boolean` in `IF` and `WHERE` clauses, it does not support declaring `boolean` variables or parameters. The `bit` data type cannot store the result of a `boolean` expression directly, even though it looks suspiciously like one.

The nearest you can get to a `boolean` data type is this:

```
-- Store the result of a boolean test.
declare @result bit
select @result = case when <boolean expression> then 1 else 0 end

-- Make use of the above result somewhere else.
if @result = 1
    ...
else
    ...
```

To add to the confusion, SQL Server Management Studio treats `bit` like `boolean` when displaying results, and ADO.NET maps `bit` to `System.Boolean` when passing data back and forth.

**Update:** To answer your latest question, use the `case when ... then 1 else 0 end` syntax in the `select` statement.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx for an "official" confirmation about the Boolean data type not being declarable nor assignable.

Comment: Sheesh, but thanks!! Back to the stone age with SQL Server